# android SQLite database removed after uninstall

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to know one thing related  sqlite in android.

When i install my app and run it and do my operation's save some data and read data.

but when i uninstall my app and install it again.

I tried to read data but it does not show any thing .It means database deleted on uninstall the app.

If yes ,how to prevent my database to uninstall.

Comment: Your database will be uninstalled when the app is uninstalled.. it cant be prevented

Comment: if you want to keep that data you want to take a back up ..

Comment: That really depends how to save your Database. If you aquire external storage and store it in external, then it can be prevented

Comment: @wtsang02 is right. That way, you could prevent the deletion, but then it would be available to everyone else as well.

Comment: kumar.if i create the db in sd card .it ll available to other also..

Comment: @KumarBibek storing your data in users phone is not safe to begin with.

Comment: Exactly... But, That's an option as well, if your data is not private.

Comment: my data is private only.i dont want to some one can see or access it.

Answer (score 8):

I'm assuming you're creating your database on the internal storage as most apps do.

When you uninstall your app, the entire data directory of the app is deleted. This includes databases, preferences, other files, caches etc.

You could try saving the database to the SD Card instead and reading from there. However, you will now lose access to the database if the user changes the SD Card or mounts it to the computer pre honeycomb.

Another option would be to back it up to a server at regular intervals and restore the backup from there manually, or implement something like the [Google BackupAgent](http://developer.android.com/google/backup/index.html), which will automatically backup data if the user configures his/her device to backup against the Google account to which it is registered.

If you're worried about your data being read by others, encrypt it using AES or some other encryption technique.

Comment: Raghav i tried with sqlcipher to encrypt but i didn not get idea how to do that.all provide me link but no one is telling the procedure for that.

Answer (score 1):

It is simple, use Google backup [service](http://developer.android.com/google/backup/index.html) or store it in another place like on your server or in user sd card.