# No SQLiteOpenHelper.onCreate call after re-install

Tags: android, installation

For testing purposes I manually remove the app I am developing from my phone.

When I re-install it using Android Studio, the `onCreate` method from `SQLiteOpenHelper` is not called. Only if I explicitely purge the app's memory in the system's app settings, it is called on next start-up.

What is happening? Is the app not completely removed during deinstallation?

**Edit 1:**
how can this database file persist, if the app is deinstalled? this can cause some unwanted behaviour! what's the best way to know that the app was just installed and when to reset everything?

**Edit 2:**

My current code looks like this:

```
public class SQLiteDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // Yes, previous db versions would get upgraded, but this 
    // should not matter for the question, because I deinstall 
    // and reinstall.
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2; 

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "AppDB";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        Log.i("info", "============================");
        Log.i("info", "SQLiteDbHelper.onCreate(...)");
        Log.i("info", "----------------------------");

        // ...

        Log.i("info", "============================");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.i("info", "============================");
        Log.i("info", "SQLiteDbHelper.onUpgrade(...)");
        Log.i("info", "oldVersion = " + oldVersion);
        Log.i("info", "newVersion = " + newVersion);
        Log.i("info", "============================");

        // ...
    }

   // ...
}
```

Comment: That's because a db is just a file located under your package name and it already exists. `OnCreate` only runs if the file doesn't exist.

Comment: @Pztar yes, but this did not explain why i still exists after deinstall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in my *AndroidManifest.xml* file:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
```

`onCreate` was never called because the database file still existed. I set `allowBackup` now to `false` and everything is removed upon deinstallation.

Answer (score 1):

You might check out [This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14555451/android-sqlite-database-removed-after-uninstall)

tl;dr, installing the database file (.db) to an sd card, or any external storage on the device will persist that database file through all uninstalls.

Check to see if you are installing the database file to an external storage device from the application.

**EDIT**
In your SQLiteOpenHelper class, the constrcutor's second argument defines the file's name and location, for instance:

```
public class MyDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

    public static final String DB_NAME = "myDb.db";

    public MyDBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    }
...
}
```

Would define a database that is associated only as your app's data. This would be deleted if you uninstalled the application.

Comment: thank u for the clarification, but i think i am already using a path which is associated with my app's data (pls see my edit). strange thing is on an emulator onCreate is called after reinstall... On my phone it is not (Sony Xperia Z3)

Comment: also preferences are not reset! i show a dialog on first start-up using a flag saved in SharedPreferences. Upon re-install the dialog is not shown either, on the emulator it is.

Comment: Hmm... That is odd behavior. I couldn't find anything online saying that your particular model of phone saved data like that. If it is phone specific you might have to uninstall data every time you delete the app, which would really suck. Have you tried uninstalling through ADB/Gradle operations?